# Print Syntax error when testing out django script

Tags: python, django

When running this

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import util


encyclopedia_list = util.list_entries()

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index")
]

for encyclopedia in encyclopedia_list:
    urlpatterns.append(path(f"{encyclopedia}", views.encyclopedia, name='encyclopedia_page')


print(urlpatterns)
```

script in a django app in order to test if the urlpatterns list is being updated acordingly I get a syntax error with the print function on the last line, any idea on what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with print. Close the parenthesis inside the loop

```
for encyclopedia in encyclopedia_list:
    urlpatterns.append(path(f"{encyclopedia}", views.encyclopedia, name='encyclopedia_page'))
```

Comment: Oh...
I'm so sorry for wasting your time with this, swear to god I spent about 15 mins looking at these 15 lines of code and didn't spot that, thank you so much hahaha

Comment: Haha sure. Happens a lot with me as well.